# Getting last post from SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I came across an interesting feature in **chat.stackoverflow.com** that enables users to see the last time of last post.
 It's like this **"The last message was posted 9 hours ago."**
Tried a format like this:

id |post |time

```
The last message was posted +time+ ago
```

I wanna ask, that how can I use php to get and display time of last post. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the time of the last post, or do you want to know how long ago it was?

Comment: calculate time different from now to time of post made...

Comment: Surely, `date("G" time() - unixTimeStampOfPost );`?

Comment: You have to store time of each post. Find the last post time (Order By `time` Column DESC). Get the difference from the current time.

Comment: @JensonMJohn u are on the way. The amin point here is that, I wanna get the last post on the table, then know the time it was posted, then differentiate it from the current time...to give a timestamp. 

like this:
**get_last_post_timestamp(time_of_last_post-current_time_now)**

Answer (score 1):

The query can look simply like this:

```
SELECT
  `date`
FROM `posts`
WHERE `date` = MAX(`date`);
```

Then you can use PHP to get the time elapsed:

```
$elapsed = new DateTime($date_from_mysql)->diff(new DateTime(/* now */));
```

**Your homework:** Output the elapsed time properly regardless if there have minutes days or even years elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a timestamp or datetime column to your database table and populate it with the correct time. The difference between the current time and the stored time can then be expressed in the appropriate time unti (e.g. hours)

You can then use the mysql or PHP date functions to get the correct format.
In Mysql it's something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW()-postdate,"%h hours ago") FROM myTable WHERE postdate = MAX(postdate)
```

or in PHP (assuming an unix timestamp and the selection of the last post already done):

```
$hoursago = date("h", time()-$myTimeStamp) . " hours ago";
```

Comment: Although both answers are possible, I like your's more because the work is done in the database server only. +1

Comment: Well that's not always appropriate, if you for example want some conditionals to choose the format (i.e. seconds, minutes, hours etc.) I'd do it outside of the database. If you always want hours then both in code and in the query can be appropriate.